# AVPlayer Reverse Playback

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation

How would one go about getting an AVPlayer object to play its video content in reverse? The AVPlayerItem class has a property called "reversePlaybackEndTime," which makes me think that reverse playback is thus possible, but I can't seem to find anything in the docs about actually doing it.

Answer (score 8):

You can `reverse play` like this as `queuePlayer` is `AVPlayer`:

Firstly get to `end` of `video`

```
CMTime durTime = self.queuePlayer.currentItem.asset.duration;
durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(durTime);
//NSLog(@"durationTime :%f : %f",durTime);
if (CMTIME_IS_VALID(durTime))
    [self.queuePlayer seekToTime:durTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
else
    NSLog(@"In valid time");
```

Now set `Rate` of `AVPlayer` to `negative` value

```
[self.queuePlayer setRate:-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you send 'play' message to the AVPlayer object it starts playing and this is equivalent to setting the rate property to 1.0. Have you tried to set that property to -1.0? I haven't Mac at the moment to test it, so if this doesn't work I'll remove my answer.

Comment: as per Apple's docs rate can be between 0.0 and 1.0. -1.0 is not a valid value. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate

Comment: Says "A value of 0.0 pauses the video, while a value of 1.0 plays the current item at its natural rate. Rates other than 0.0 and 1.0 can be used if the associated player item returns true for the AVPlayerItem properties canPlaySlowForward or canPlayFastForward. *Negative rate value ranges are supported if the player item returns true for the canPlayReverse*, canPlaySlowReverse, and canPlayFastReverse properties."