# Reverse video playback in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, media

I want to play video backward in AVPlayer. I have tried with changing rates property to -1.0, and although it did work it was not smooth. Is there any way through which I can smoothly play videos backward?

Comment: the video playing is an interesting thing, because the video has keyframes at every X frame, and the frames between the keyframes are just storing the changes of the image from the previous frame (not the entire frame). so playing backward a video is not just about changing the order of the frames, because the frames are in relationship with the previous one (not with the next one!) and, generally, you don't change the order of the frames to get the backward version, most of the cases you should re-render the video again. this is the generic reason why you have problem with videos.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest me any solution for reverse playback of video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310945/mpmovieplayercontroller-playing-movies-in-reverse-backwards-is-not-smooth-in-i

Answer (score 9):

As stated in the comments, the problem is with keyframes and the fact that most codecs are not designed to play backwards. There are 2 options for re-encoding the video that doesn't require you to actually reverse the video in editing.

1. Make every frame a keyframe. I've seen this work well for codecs like H.264 that rely on keyframes. Basically if every frame is a key frame, then each frame can be decoded without relying on any previous frames so it's effectively the same as playing forward.
2. Use a codec that doesn't use keyframes and non-keyframes (basically all frames are always keyframes). PhotoJPEG is one such option, although I'm not completely sure if it plays back on iOS. I would think so. It works great on a Mac.

Note that either of this options will result in larger file sizes compared to typical "keyframe every x frames" encoded video.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reach at the end of the current item and then set the rate to the negative value. Something like this:

`-(void)reversePlay
{
    CMTime durTime = myPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration;
    if (CMTIME_IS_VALID(durTime))
    {
        [myPlayer seekToTime:durTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
        [myPlayer setRate:-1.0];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Invalid time");
}`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104363/701043