# Looping effect for video in iOS like Boomerang app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Like the title, I would like to ask if there is any tutorial or any plugin in iOS to make the looping effect in video like Boomerang app on iOS?

I have made a search on Google but found no result.

Comment: My SDLoopingVideoBackgroundView class on GitHub does exactly this: https://github.com/SolsmaHawk/SDLoopingVideoBackgroundView

Comment: @SolsmaDev it's not, you know the looping effect like Boomerang app?, it keeps playing a short video forward and backward, not just finish the video and automatically begin from the beginning

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the boomerang app and was just going by your description. It sounds like you would like to play the video in reverse after playing forward in a loop? This looks like a way to accomplish reverse playback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16104363/2880537